# Nodejitsu Design Decisions

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, nginx, system-administration

Why does Nodejitsu tend to prefer doing things in Node.js, e.g., [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) & [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), instead of using nginx or Apache?

Answer (score 1):

We actually prefer to do things in C. We don't use `forever` in production, we use `aeternum`: https://github.com/opsmezzo/aeternum